# Surface normal and differential?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am dealing with a Monge patch(surface) defined by the three coordinates $[x, y, f(x,y)]^T$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In my text book, the following is said:

> Assume that the measured value of the unit normal at some point $(x,
>  y)$ is $(a(x, y), b(x, y), c(x, y))$. Then
>
> $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{a(x,y)}{c(x,y)} \quad
>  \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{b(x,y)}{c(x,y)}
>  $$

Why is this true?

Here is the actual book content:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The vector $(a,b,c)$ has to be some scalar multiple of $(f_x,f_y,-1)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi hmm can you take a look at my post after I have included the actual book content? If what you say is true, isn't the author quite unclear do you think?

Comment: The author is plainly mistaken. They do not have the factor of $-1$, which is a consequence of implicit function theorem. See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html#:~:text=The%20normal%20vector%2C%20often%20simply,pointing%20normal%20are%20usually%20distinguished.) for more details.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah that is frustrating! Hate when you have to doubt whatever the author says :(

Comment: It's a cardinal rule of math, trust but verify :) It feels good to build the confidence in your own skills to be able to come to your own conclusions. A classmate of mine found a mistake in the proof of the residue theorem in a highly respected gold standard book of complex analysis written by a fields medalist, which passed many decades of editorial look-overs, if it makes you feel better. What is this a textbook on, by the way?

Comment: @NinadMunshi "Computer Vision: A Modern Approach 2nd Edition - Forsyth and Ponce". Thanks for sharing your experience :)

Comment: Seems the contents are not the final. Also "-" in the last equation should be a equal sign "=".

Comment: @MathArt nono that was just me forgetting to include the following text saying "should be small at each point" :D

Comment: @NinadMunshi But is it actually possible to specify the differential w.r.t. a variable by using coordinates of the normal, like the author attempted to do? In that case, what should the formula(the one equating the differential wrt x to the quotient a(x,y)/c(x,y)) have been?